# Constructing new output object graphics

Tags: output-formatting

Occasionally, when you ask Mathematica to carry out a task for which there is no good compact representation for the output, it will generate a special icon in v10, or an abbreviation in lower versions.

For example (in v10):

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == 2, x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 4}]
```

> [image]

giving just the essential information about the output; `Domain` and `Output`.  Applying `FullForm` on this output reveals the internal data.
Clicking on the "+" sign gives a little bit more information about the function.

How does one mimic this behavior in user-defined functions (that could potentially go into publicly used packages)?

---

**Concrete task**
Here is a function that can generate a long expression:

```
SetAttributes[tap, Orderless]
myFunc[list_List] := Expand[Total[(Total[#]) tap @@ # & /@ Tuples[list, 2]]^2]
```

In particular, it gives a polynomial in `tap[x,y]` (which is symmetric under $x\leftrightarrow y$).  For example, `myFunc[{a,b}]` generates `4a^2 tap[a, a]^2 + 8a^2 tap[a, a]tap[a, b] ...`.

Now, instead of displaying the whole expression, how would I make it generate a little graphic?  Let's have it display two pieces of information: (1) the different `tap`s that are in the expression, and (2) the number of terms.  For example let's have the graphic look like:

[image]

It should still be possible to use this output as an input to future evaluations.  And ideally, applying `FullForm` should display the original polynomial.